# How to handle multiple input fields through single component in React

Tags: reactjs, input

I have the following app, that allows to choose the number of nights in the hotel.

[image]

The code that I wrote so far causes the following: when i click random "+" button all input fields change number simultaneously which is of course not a behaviour that i want to achieve. Can anyone tell me how to handle all input fields seperately and calculate total price (number of nights * price per night) for all nights?

HotelList Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './HotelList.scss';
import axios from 'axios';
import Hotel from '../Hotel/Hotel';


    const HotelList = () => {
    
        const [hotel, setHotel] = useState([]);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [error, setError] = useState('');
        const [nights, setNights] = useState(0);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                await axios.get('https://60007292cb21e10017af8f04.mockapi.io/api/v1/hotels')
                .then(response => {
                    setHotel(response.data);
                    setLoading(false);
    
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    setLoading(false);
                    setError(error.message);
                })
            }
            fetchData();
        }, [])
    
    
        const addNights = () => {
            setNights(nights + 1);
        }
    
        return(
            <div>
                {!loading ? <div>
                    {hotel.map(htl => {
                        return <div key={htl.id} >
                                    <hr/>
                                        <Hotel 
                                        title={htl.hotel} 
                                        description={htl.description} 
                                        price={htl.price} 
                                        image={htl.photoURL}
                                        nights={nights}
                                        addNights={addNights}/>
                                </div>
                            })}
                            <p>Total price: </p>
                </div> : <div className="ring"><div className="lds-dual-ring"></div></div>}
                
            </div>
    
        );
    };
    
    export default HotelList;
```

Hotel Component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Hotel.scss';

const Hotel = ({ title, description, price, image, nights, addNights }) => {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="img">
                <img src={image} alt="hotel" />
            </div>
            <div className="info">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="vl"></div>
            <div className="price">
                <button>-</button>
                <input type="number" value={nights}/>
                <button onClick={addNights}>+</button>
            </div>
            <div className="inner-container">
                <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                <p>${price}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Hotel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to identify every checkbox state with a unique identifier.
and when click, it will update the state based on that identifier.

try this solution.

**HotelList Component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./HotelList.scss";
import axios from "axios";
import Hotel from "./Hotel";

const HotelList = () => {
  const [hotel, setHotel] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [nights, setNights] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios
        .get("https://60007292cb21e10017af8f04.mockapi.io/api/v1/hotels")
        .then((response) => {
          setHotel(response.data);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setLoading(false);
          setError(error.message);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const addNights = (id) => {
    let nightsCount = nights[id] || 0;
    setNights({ ...nights, [id]: nightsCount + 1 });
  };

  const removeNights = (id) => {
    if (nights[id] > 0) setNights({ ...nights, [id]: nights[id] - 1 });
  };
    
  return (
    <div>
      {!loading ? (
        <div>
          {hotel.map((htl) => {
            return (
              <div key={htl.id}>
                <hr />
                <Hotel
                  id={htl.id}
                  title={htl.hotel}
                  description={htl.description}
                  price={htl.price}
                  image={htl.photoURL}
                  nights={nights}
                  addNights={addNights}
                  removeNights={removeNights}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          <p>Total price: </p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="ring">
          <div className="lds-dual-ring"></div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HotelList;
```

**Hotel Component**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Hotel.scss";

const Hotel = ({ id, title, description, price, image, nights, addNights, removeNights }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="img">
        <img src={image} alt="hotel" />
      </div>
      <div className="info">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="vl"></div>
      <div className="price">
        <button onClick={() => removeNights(id)}>-</button>
        <input type="number" value={nights[id]} />
        <button onClick={() => addNights(id)}>+</button>
      </div>
      <div className="inner-container">
        <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
        <p>${price}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hotel;
```

[live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-mclaren-qi39m?file=/src/HotelList.js:0-1779)

**class-based component**

```
class HotelListClass extends Component {
  state = {
    hotel: [],
    loading: true,
    error: "",
    nights: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    await axios
      .get("https://60007292cb21e10017af8f04.mockapi.io/api/v1/hotels")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ hotel: response.data });
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.setState({ error: error.message });
      });
  };

  addNights = (id) => {
    const { nights } = this.state;
    let nightsCount = nights[id] || 0;
    this.setState({
      nights: { ...nights, [id]: nightsCount + 1 }
    });
  };

  removeNights = (id) => {
    const { nights } = this.state;
    if (nights[id] > 0) {
      this.setState({
        nights: { ...nights, [id]: nights[id] - 1 }
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, hotel, nights } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {!loading ? (
          <div>
            {hotel.map((htl) => {
              return (
                <div key={htl.id}>
                  <hr />
                  <Hotel
                    id={htl.id}
                    title={htl.hotel}
                    description={htl.description}
                    price={htl.price}
                    image={htl.photoURL}
                    nights={nights}
                    addNights={this.addNights}
                    removeNights={this.removeNights}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <p>Total price: </p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="ring">
            <div className="lds-dual-ring"></div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HotelListClass;
```

[live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-mclaren-qi39m?file=/src/HotelListClass.js)

Comment: Thank you very much,
Do you have an idea, what do i do wrong if i want to do the same in a class based component?

`addNights = (id) => {
        let nightsCount = this.state.nights[id] || 0;
        this.setState({...this.state.nights, [id]: nightsCount + 1});
    }`

Comment: Code above doesn't work in class component

Comment: state looks as follows:

`state = {
        hotel: [],
        loading: true,
        error: '',
        nights: {
            1: 1,
            2: 1,
            3: 1,
            4: 1,
            5: 1
        },
        totalPrice: null
    }`

Comment: @Przemo, in the code menthioned above you probably forget to set the state property, 'nights' in your case, your function should be like this.                                                                                                         
 addNights = (id) => {         let nightsCount = this.state.nights[id] || 0;         this.setState({nights: {...this.state.nights, [id]: nightsCount + 1}} );     }

Comment: also, check the updated code for class-based component